# Can I use a windows image as a guest OS for Azure WebRole?

Tags: azure

I have this situation where I need to install and configure various things in the OS. I know that I can use VMs for this, but I need the code deployment functionality and wonder if there is a way to have a custom OS image and also be able to do code deployments using visual studio publish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom OS images is not option for Web/Worker roles (i.e. True PaaS Cloud Services). However you add OS customizations via a [Startup Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg456327.aspx). I can hardly think of anything that is not possible via a startup task.

Comment: Em.. What about VM roles? Don't they allow exactly this?

Comment: "VM Role" is retired. There are Azure Virtual Machines - a IaaS offer. But they do not offer the scaling capabilities you get with PaaS, and a lot of other goodies (such as co-located Cache, OS Updates, etc.)! And I would only opt for a IaaS soltion when I really can not achieve what I want with a PaaS! And there is not much I cannot do with PaaS.